# Equivalent function of datenum(datestring) of Matlab in Python

Tags: python, matlab

In Matlab, when I run "[datenum](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)" function as the following;

```
datenum(1970, 1, 1);
```

I get the following output:

```
719529
```

I'm trying to find the equivalent function or script which is gonna give me the same output. But, unfortunately I couldn't find an enough explanation on the internet to do this.

I have looked at this tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html, but it didn't help.

Could you tell me, how can I get the same output in python?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the datetime module and the toordinal() function

```
from datetime import date

print date.toordinal(date(1970,1,1))

719163
```

To get the date you got you would use

```
print date.toordinal(date(1971,1,2))

719529
```

or for easier conversion

```
print date.toordinal(date(1970,1,1))+366

719529
```

I believe the reason the date is off is due to the fact datenum starts its counting from january 0, 0000 which this doesn't recognize as a valid date. You will have to counteract the change in the starting date by adding one to the year and day. The month doesn't matter because the first month in datetime is equal to 0 in datenum

Comment: So, will I be able to add datestring as a parameter in "toordinal()" function?

Comment: `date.toordinal(date(1970, 1, 1))` gives a result of `719163`, which does not match the result in the question

Comment: Please show how do you get output `719529` with input `1970, 1, 1` using your command.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, horns and Alex.S. Currently I don't have Matlab in my computer, that's why I'm using online matlab compiler on this link: http://octave-online.net/ And I get this result on that page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SirParselot. Your answer is true. There is a 366 difference between MATLAB and Python.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers return an integer.
MATLAB's datenum does not necessarily return an integer. The following code retuns the same answer as MATLAB's datenum:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def datenum(d):
    return 366 + d.toordinal() + (d - dt.fromordinal(d.toordinal())).total_seconds()/(24*60*60)

d = dt.strptime('2019-2-1 12:24','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
dn = datenum(d)
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that your solution really helped me

Answer (score 2):

You can substract [`date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) objects in Python:

```
>>> date(2015, 10, 7) - date(1, 1, 1)
datetime.timedelta(735877)

>>> (date(2015, 10, 7) - date(1, 1, 1)).days
735877
```

Just take care to use an epoch that is useful to your needs.

Comment: Hello Kay, do you know why do I get "'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'days'" error? :)

Comment: Probably you missed the parentheses. `date(...) - date(...) → timedelta`, and `timedelta` has a `days` attribute.

Comment: This gives almost the same answer as mine which isn't right either. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @SirParselot, yes, we both use `0001-01-01` as epoch, but Matlab uses `0000-00-00` which I assume is December 31th 1 BC. That's why I said "Just take care to use an epoch that is useful to your needs", because Matlab's epoch is strange. :)