# how to convert a python date in to an integer

Tags: python, date

Struggling with something that should be easy:

```
today = '26/8/2018'
start = '1/8/2018'
diff = today - start
```

diff gives us 26 days

how do I take the integer value of this datetime? i.e. 26?

basically, im trying to calc a daycount fraction, (diff / 365) * 10,000 say, but it wont work.

My actual values I have are:

```
0       304.548
1       371.397
2       350.466
3      -3574.36
4       255.452
```

and im trying to multiply them by:
         duration

```
0     13 days      
1     2 days       
2     1 days         
3     20 days       
4      7 days
```

But I get:

```
0       TimedeltaIndex(['3959 days 02:57:32.054794',  ...
1       TimedeltaIndex([ '4828 days 03:56:42.739725', ...
2       TimedeltaIndex([ '4556 days 01:18:54.246575', ...
3       TimedeltaIndex(['-46467 days +08:52:36.164383'...
4       TimedeltaIndex(['3320 days 21:02:27.945204',  ...
```

desired output is 
`0       3959.124`     as an integer (304.548*13), not as a daycount

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991934/equivalent-function-of-datenumdatestring-of-matlab-in-python) question is relevant.

Comment: Why are you trying to do `diff/365 * 10000`? A years isn't 365 days, it's 365 or 366 depending on the year, or 365.2425 days on average,

Comment: In financial math, interest rates are calculated using actual days/365 or sometimes 30/360 (so assumptions are built in).
For my example, I am happy to use 365 days per year.
However, despite Ashish's solution working as expected, my code wont work.. ugh.. 
I have a series of time deltas, e.g. Timedelta('13 days 00:00:00')
but when multiplying by 304.548, I get another timedelta:
TimedeltaIndex(['3959 days 02:57:32.054794',  ...

and the entire series of timedeltas doesn't recognise ".days"
statistics['duration'].days
gives an error:
"'Series' object has no attribute 'days'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [4]: diff = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=8, day=1)

In [5]: diff.days
Out[5]: 25
```

Then you can do something like:

```
In [10]: diff.days / 365 * 10000
Out[10]: 684.931506849315
```

Comment: Thanks! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646200/python-convert-timedelta-to-int-in-a-dataframe/42247228
also helped!